# Uploaded files have permission 000

Tags: permissions, uploads

two days ago i updated wp to the newest version and this problem occurs since then.
when i upload files to the media library, their file permissions are set to 000. means no rights. the files are copied to the server, but since nobody has any right to read / write / execute i can't do anything with it (the files are defenetly on the server, but wp can not create the thumbnails etc. and i can't view the files with my ftp client, but when i download them, they are just fine). the uploads folder and all containing folders have 777 and i cant find any solution to this. is it some hosting problem, that just popped up??

thanks for the help

Comment: It seems your site is affected by some malware.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i deactivated all the plugins and reactivated them back again, just to find out than one of those was currupted / outdated. now everything works fine again.